# SNAT with firewall-cmd?

Tags: networking, centos, iptables, nat

I have an interface with multiple IP Addresses (on CentOS 7), which is in zone "external" (with masquerade on). I want to specify that, if a connectiona attempt to a specific address goes out, to use a specific outgoing address. Something like:

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d <my-destination-ip> \
    -j SNAT --to <my-source-ip>
```

I couldn't find anything for `firewall-cmd`. I also would like to explicitly define the "default outgoing IP".